# mv: target 'Nfilename' is not a directory error help

Tags: command-line, scripts, virtualbox

I'm new to Ubuntu and coding in general but have to use it to do some analysis of molecular sequencing data and I am stuck!

I recently moved from my laptop to a more powerful PC (both with a VM mounted in it) and a piece of my script now no longer works.

The code I use to split one file (Map.txt) into individual files then rename each file and finally add the header row from the original file to each individual file is:

```
$ tail -n +2 Map.txt | split -l 1

$ awk '{cmd="echo " $0 ">" $1; system(cmd)}' x*

$ for file in `ls N*`; do echo "`head -1 Map.txt`" > tmp; cat $file >> tmp; mv –f tmp $file; done
```

Each command is run individually but I now get an error saying:

```
mv: target 'NC2B7' is not a directory
```

when I run the third command above ($ for file in etc). Im not sure why this command is suddenly not working, I was using an old Oracle VM VirtualBox on my laptop and now am using Oracle VM VirtualBox v5.2.18 with ubuntu 16.04 to run QIIME.

Can someone tell me what could be the cause of this and/ or what the third command should now be?

Comment: Rather than attempting to "fix" your code, perhaps it would be better to post a sample of your `Map.txt` file and desired output file(s) and we can maybe suggest a more robust approach?

Comment: Also the output of `ls N*` would be interesting. I suspect spaces in their filenames so `mv` gets called with more than two parameters and thus expects the last one to be a directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$ for file in `ls N*`; do echo "`head -1 Map.txt`" > tmp; cat $file >> tmp; mv –f tmp $file; done
```

to

```
$ for file in `ls N*`; do echo "`head -1 Map.txt`" > tmp; cat $file >> tmp; mv -f tmp $file; done
```

The difference is not easy to see, but in your command you used a long dash instead of the normal dash in the `mv`-command, `-f`-option. I tested it and it worked.

To prevent accidents with filenames containing spaces you should add some double-quotes:

```
$ for file in `ls N*`; do echo "`head -1 Map.txt`" > tmp; cat "$file" >> tmp; mv -f tmp "$file"; done
```

You could also simplify the whole command to

```
$ for file in N*; do head -1 Map.txt > tmp; cat "$file" >> tmp; mv -f tmp "$file";
```

which was suggested by @PerlDuck. Of course, I tested this suggestion before adding it to this answer.

Comment: @PerlDuck  Your beautiful suggestion looks obviously simpler, my intention was to find the bug, not to make it simpler. I'm still a beginner with Bash, far from being a professional. Thank you for sharing your knowledge!

Comment: @PerlDuck Added your suggestion to the answer after testing.

Comment: Thank you all, @mook765 especially, it seems the change from a normal dash to a long dash knocked my code out. It is now working again = one happy scientist!